# debian-policy states required targets, is dh pass ok?

Tags: debian, packaging, deb, debhelper

https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#main-building-script-debian-rules

Document in question ^

**I am learning to build debian packages and read above policy, specifically about the main *(required)* targets.**

- I was told that I don't need to specify the targets if I use dh. Is this valid to the policy that dh delivers these targets?

.. of course one will have to override where the `dh` commands fail to do a proper job.

- Is there any case where you absolutely need to manually define targets for compatibility, or would it be rejected solely for missing the targets explicitly defined?

Comment: If dh fails it job, tell dh how to do tasks explicitly, within dh framework (usually with relevant files in debian/). Or do it all manually (it is also not complex, just remember to check and ev. update debian/rules at every policy change). Mixing gives too much troubles (but if you are a Kung-Fu-DebHelper, but so, you will just do it for debugging, to improve DH).

Comment: The question is just about compatability with the debian policy. Will dh's auto targets be accepted in the official repo etc? Since it states (required) it seems that they are

Comment: The confusion becomes, if it really means all these targets should be handled- and not required as in the sense we define them manually and then put the appropriate dh steps in there.

Comment: Is https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh.1.en.html answering your question: you have override, and interaction with debian/rules and dh. For policy: you need a good example, and check if there are good alternative (ev. asking debian-devel ML). Exceptions and interpretations are common (so where is debian-policy list).

Comment: Sort of, it lists all the targets, but yes you are right I probably should ask Debian straight up to get the most correct answer. Do you see why it can seem a little bit confusing? The policy could say "NOTE: dh catches all required targets by default, there is no need to manually define the targets"

Comment: Policy is not the definitive documentation (it miss a lot of stuff). You should get it together to Debian Developer's Reference. There were discussion to improve and merge documentation, but since a lot of time, I didn't follow such discussions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the required targets do not need to be specified explicitly in `debian/rules`. The policy only requires that `debian/rules` "implements" those targets; that is, if you call `debian/rules` with any of those targets, it should do the appropriate thing.

There are many packages in the archive now which use `dh` and which don't declare those required targets explicitly in the `debian/rules` makefile.